# How to limit map bounds on toggle button "world view" and "country view"

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Im trying to make a map with a button to toggle "world view" or a specific "country view"

I tried to use this [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/restrict-bounds/), which is limiting view to bounds. But this solution does not let me toggle between bbox-country and bbox-worldview after the map has initialized.

How do i change the maxBounds after map init load?

```
var bounds = [
[-74.04728500751165, 40.68392799015035], // Southwest coordinates
[-73.91058699000139, 40.87764500765852] // Northeast coordinates
];
 
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
center: [-73.9978, 40.7209],
zoom: 13,
maxBounds: bounds // Need maxBounds to be changable after init
});
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056472/mapbox-fitbounds-invalid-lnglat-object-nan-nan/63058036#63058036)

Comment: That only fly you to the location, it does not limit bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, and its very easy

When you want to limit bounds on initial, add the `maxBounds` property to map init like so:

```
   var bounds = [
      [-22.763672, 54.622978], // Southwest coordinates
      [58.710938, 73.677264] // Northeast coordinates
   ];

   var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        maxBounds: bounds
    });
```

If you want to not limit bounds again do:

```
map.setMaxBounds(null);
```

If you want to add bounds again, or change bounds

```
map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

//flyto here is important (if you dont fly to new bounds user cannot pan or zoom map since it is stuck out of bounds
map.flyTo({
  center: [3.606842488358609, 63.0207009783135],
  zoom: 4.5
});
```